# Who is the current Master of Legio Custodes?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Not much has been written about the Legio Custodes in recent times.

`I guess it would be a boring read to write about soldiers guarding the Emperors throne room`.

What I am interested in knowing is What is the name of current Master of the Legio (M41/42)? Traditionally the head of the Legio is also one of the High Lords of Terra so there has to exist a record of who it is somewhere in all the books, e-books, short stories, White Dwarf, pc games, etc. that seem to be coming out of Games Workshop at an alarmingly fast-paced intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the novel *Watchers of the Throne: The Emperor's Legion* by Chris Wraight, the current Captain-General of the Adeptus Custodes as of the Thirteenth Black Crusade (999.M41, basically, current events as of our year 2017) is [Trajann Valoris](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Trajann_Valoris).

There's not a whole lot of information about the Custodes leadership, particularly outside of the Horus Heresy series, but according to [Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Captain-General), the known Captain-Generals of the Custodes are:

- Constantin Valdor, during the Great Crusade and Horus Heresy.
- Beyreuth: Captain-General during the War of the Beast (544.M32)
- Trajann Valoris: Captain-General during the Thirteenth Black Crusade (999.M41)

*Watchers of the Throne: The Emperor's Legion*, as well as Wraight's other novel *Vaults of Terra: The Carrion Throne*, seem to concentrate on some of the more seldom-seen elements of the Imperium, including the Custodes, the Silent Sisterhood, and Terra itself.

Comment: There are other Captain Generals as well - Aesoth Koumadra: Was Captain General between the 33rd and 39th Millennia. - Galahoth: Custodians suffered from stagnation. Disappeared during the late 40th - early 41st Millennia. - Andros Launceddre: Trajann Valoris' predecessor. Slain during the Battle of the Gilded Pyre, thanks to false information from the doomscryer (psykers in the service of the Custodians).